# window.open() used in javascript not working in firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax post call like this,

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(){

    $("#submit").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#submit").prop("value","Loading...");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myURL',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "mailid" : mailid,
            "a1" : a1,
            "a2" : a2,
            "a3" : a3,
            "a4" : a4,
            "a5" : a5,
            "a6" : a6,
            "a7" : a7,
            "a8" : a8,
            "a9" : a9,
            "a10" :a10,
            "dob" : age,
            "filledBy" : filledBy
        }),
        success: function () {
            //to open the score page
            window.open("score.html","_top");

            $("#submit").prop("disabled",false);
            $("#submit").prop("value","Get My Score");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);

        }
    });
});
```

in the success function window.open() works fine in chrome, i.e., page gets redirected to score.html but it doesn't work in edge,Firefox and internet explorer browsers instead it just refreshes the same page. Is there a alternate way to use window.open() so that it redirects to "Score.html" irrespective of what browser is used?

Comment: Could you provide an example at jsfiddle? Thank you.

Comment: So is the problem the ajax success or the `window.open`?  What if you just add a `window.open` inside the click event?  Does it work in all browsers?

Comment: sounds like a pop up blocker if it is actually getting into the success method

Comment: Yeah i believe it's a pop-up blocker, i tried adding "async:false" to my ajax method and window.open() works fine but adding async:false doesn't let these two lines pass ,                                                   
          $("#submit").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#submit").prop("value","Loading...");                                                                               Is there a way to prevent the pop up blocker without using async:false?

Answer (score 0):

FireFox and Edge allow `window.open` just on click and in other situations (as well as ajax success) , ask the users if they want to allow opening a new window. User may also choose that the page not ask this question again.

If you want to redirect to a new page use this insetad:

```
 window.location.href="score.html";
```

Comment: I tried using window.location.href and still no change, the page refreshes but doesn't open the new html page

Comment: Opening a new window needs a physical click or user permission. Window.location is just a suggestion to finish the operation using the current window. @PKK